# Установка модулей Python offline

Tags: python, модули

При установке модулей Python в offline они не устанавливаются, требуя модуль flit_core>=3.3. Но этот модуль установлен, его версия 3.9.0. Я пробовал заменить его на 3.3.0, но и это не помогло.
Устанавливаю модули из скачанных с PyPi.org файлов в формате tar.gz (из whl тоже пробовал).
Что я делаю не так ?

*Дополнительная информация.*

Версия Python 3.9.
Устанавливать пытаюсь модули packaging 23.1 и wheel 0.41.2 - оба не ставятся.
Пример моей команды установки:

```
  pip install "C:\Distr\python 3.9.0\new\packaging-23.2.tar.gz" --user --retries 1 --no-index
Ответ:
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flit_core>=3.3 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for flit_core>=3.3
```

При этом проверяю наличие модуля:

```
  python -c "print(__import__('flit_core').__version__)"
  3.9.0
```

Comment: вам питон пишет, *наоборот*, что не может найти дистрибутив, соответствующий flit_core >=3.3, а не то, что он не может найти этот самый flit_core.

Comment: @strawdog а зачем он ищет дистрибутив для пакета, который уже установлен?

Comment: @strawdog Я специально залез внутрь архива с устанавливаемым модулем и нашёл там файл pyproject.toml со строкой 'requires = ["flit_core >=3.3"]'. Я так понял, что это как раз требования для установки данного модуля. Разве нет  ?

Comment: @ВадимСухотин не модуля, а пакета. Строго говоря, название пакета и название модуля вполне могут не совпадать - например, модуль PIL лежит в пакете Pillow (хотя обычно всё-таки совпадают)

Comment: А вообще у меня whl-пакет вполне поставился. В чём у вас проблема с whl?

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, вы побудили меня ещё раз проверить скачанный и перенесённый на компьютер whl-файл. Оказалось, что он у меня там нулевой длины. Заново его перенёс - и установка выполнилась. И wheel из whl-файла установился. Я с этими модулями, которые потребовались нашим пользователям, мучаюсь с перерывами уже с августа, чуть ли не за каждым скопированным тянется цепочка зависимостей. Почти все модули установить удалось, осталось чуть-чуть. Уже голова  распухла.

Comment: Ну вроде использование чего-то типа `pip download --prefer-binary` должно успешно скачать все whl-пакеты со всеми зависимостями

Comment: (правда, стоит иметь в виду, что это скачает бинарники для текущей ОС и текущей версии питона, и если у «наших пользователей» версия окажется не та, то будет ой)